# Why doesn't the "naive" scalar product for $SO(n)$ yield something invariant?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

By definition, for $SO(n)$ we have $g^T g=1$ for $g \in SO(n)$.

Given some vector $v \in V$ and some representation $R: SO(N) \rightarrow \mathrm{Lin}(V)$, the defining condition above tells us immediately

$$ v^T v \rightarrow (R(g)v)^T R(g)v = v^T v$$

$ \rightarrow $ The usual scalar product is invariant under $SO(n)$ transformations.

A useful way to think about representations is in terms of weights, where we use the eigenvectors of the Cartan generators of the corresponding algebra as basis for $V$. These basis vectors are labelled by the corresponding eigenvalues of the Cartan generators.

A trivial example is $SO(3)$, where we have for the 3-dimensional fundamental representation the basis vectors, $(1),(0),(-1)$, where I labelled them as explained above.

Therefore an arbitrary element of the 3-dim representation is

$$
v = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\\c \end{pmatrix} = a(1) + b(0) + c(-1)
$$

Something invariant (belonging to the 1-dim representations)has always all labels zero, here $(0)$. The "naive" scalar product yields

$$ v^T v = a^2(1)^T(1) + b^2(0)^T(0) + c^2(-1)^T (-1) $$

I learned in [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198519613) that the labels simply get added if we multiply two vectors, therefore

$$ \rightarrow v^T v= a^2(2)+b^2(0)+c^2(-2) $$

This is certainly not something invariant.

As I wrote this, I noticed that the error must be that the label gets a minus sign if we transpose the state. This would yield

$$
\begin{align} v^T v & =  a^2(1)^T(1) + b^2(0)^T(0) + c^2(-1)^T (-1)  \\[8pt]
& =  a^2(-1)(1) + b^2(0)(0) + c^2(+1) (-1)  = a^2(0) + b^2(0)+c^2(0)
\end{align}
$$

as it should be.

*Therefore my question*: **Why does this sign change for the eigenvalues of the Cartan generators happen for the transposed vectors?**

Comment: I found $\displaystyle\vphantom{\frac\int{\displaystyle\int}} v^T v = a^2|1>^T|1>+b^2|0>^T|0>+c^2|-1>^T|-1> = a^2|-1>|1>+b^2|0>+c^2|1>|-1> = a^2|0>+b^2|0>+c^2|0> $ and changed it to $\displaystyle\vphantom{\frac\int{\displaystyle\int}} v^T v = a^2|1\rangle^T|1\rangle+b^2|0\rangle^T|0\rangle+c^2|{-1} \rangle^T|{- 1}\rangle = a^2|{-1}\rangle|1\rangle+b^2 |0\rangle + c^2 |1\rangle|{-1}\rangle = a^2|0\rangle + b^2|0\rangle +c^2|0\rangle$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Just for curiosity, but why do you still have kets instead of bras when you take transpose to them?

Comment: A couple of typesetting oddities: In $b^2|0>+c^2|0>$, the software treats the plus sign as a unary rather than binary operation symbol, so you don't see the same spacing between the plus sign and $c^2$ that you see if you write $5+c^2$.  That is not surprising since if you write something like $5>+c^2$ it is indeed a unary thing.  But then in $c^2|-1\rangle$ it treats the minus sign as a binary operator, which is incorrect.  So I coded it as c^2|{-1}\rangle, so that you see $c^2|{-1}\rangle$, with spacing appropriate to a unary rather than binary use of the minus sign. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for your edits and your explanation. This makes a lot of sense I was always wondering how I can write pretty bras and kets here. Unfortunately I changed them again, because I noticed that my notation was really unfortunate and confusing. Weight vectors are conventionally not written as kets, but as numbers in brackets.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks for your comment. I think my notation was unnecessary confusion and I changed it. I do not really know what happens to a weight vector when it gets "transposed". A usual ket would become a bra, of course.  I can only assume that the labels get flipped for some reason and that is what I'm trying to understand with my question.

Comment: @JakobH : If you just google "latex symbols" you can find things like this. (What we use here is not LaTeX but MathJax.  But it's way of coding mathematical notation is largely the same.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Transpose means in some sense (that can be made precise, but then you need to give more precise definitions of the vectors) going to the dual space, and looking at the dual basis. This, indeed, results in a change of sign for the weight. It is IMO a bit dangerous to define multiplication of weight vectors like that. A tensor product is clearly meant, so such a notation hides many things. IIRC in quantum mechanics you can sometimes do that, when all the representations reside inside a bigger space, where a product is defined.